# Satisfying the trigonometric equation with the roots found on solving.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

This is the question,

[image]

When I am solving this I am getting the equation

[image]

$$(2x)(3x+2)(x-3)=0$$

When I am putting $x=-\frac{2}{3}$ and $x=3$ the equation is satisfied and when I am putting $x=0$ the equation goes like $$\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Clearly, it satisfies the equation but can I do it this way, as the range of tan inverse x is ($\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$).

Moreover, can you check if the $x=-2/3$ satisfies the equation?

This is how I am solving it,

[image]

Comment: Could describe the process for arriving at this equation ? Be careful when manipulating the arctangent.

Comment: See, I have added the method of solving.

Comment: Not sure if 0 would count either.  $\frac20$ isn't a number.

Comment: @Mike Is my solution for x=-2/3 correct?

Comment: I'd have to agree with stlinex.  The tangents of both sides may be equal, but the left side is negative while the right side is positive, so both sides can't be equal.

Answer (score 2):

When $x=-2/3$, then LHS$<0$ and RHS$>0$.

With $A=\arctan \frac{1}{2x+1}$, $B=\arctan \frac{1}{4x+1}$, $C=\arctan \frac{2}{x^2}$, what you solve is
$$\tan (A+B)=\tan C,$$
and it may happen that
$A+B=C+k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Just check each possible answer.

The solution $3$ is OK, since $A>0$, $B>0$, $C>0$ and $A+B< \pi$.

With $x=-\frac{2}{3}$, $A,B<0$, $C>0$, so we must have $A+B=C-\pi$.

Comment: Is my calculation for x =-2/3 correct?